# Beginner - XSLT replace character in a value of an attribute

Tags: xml, xslt

**Input XML is:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Order_Root>
   <Header Info="Some Info" Info2="More Info" Info3="More Info">
   <Order Number="1" ID="1234/5678 Date="1/23/2018 10:53:00 AM">
      <OrderCharges Charge="0.00000" />
   </Order>
   <Order Number="2" ID="1234/5678 Date="1/23/2018 10:53:00 AM">
      <OrderCharges Charge="0.00000" />
   </Order>
   <Order Number="3" ID="1234/5678 Date="1/23/2018 10:53:00 AM">
      <OrderCharges Charge="0.00000" />
   </Order>
   </Header>
</Order_Root>
```

**XSLT looks like this:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="Order">
        <xsl:variable name="url">
           <xsl:value-of select="@Number"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="ProductID">
           <xsl:value-of select="@ID"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:result-document method="xml" href="{$url}_{$ProductId}.xml">
            <SplitOrder>
            <Header>
                <xsl:copy-of select="../@*"></xsl:copy-of>
                <xsl:copy-of select="." />
            </Header>
            </SplitOrder>
        </xsl:result-document>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Unfortunately when i run this through i get an output which is a folder named "1_1234" with an xml inside the folder called "5678".
So i understand that it is the forward slash in the value of the attribute ID that is causing this.
I amended the xsl to try and replace the / with a hyphen, however this doesn't seem to be working for me.

XSLT change:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="Order">
        <xsl:variable name="url">
           <xsl:value-of select="@Number"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="ProductID" select="@ID">
           <xsl:value-of select="replace(.,/,-)"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:result-document method="xml" href="{$url}_{$ProductId}.xml">
            <SplitOrder>
            <Header>
                <xsl:copy-of select="../@*"></xsl:copy-of>
                <xsl:copy-of select="." />
            </Header>
            </SplitOrder>
        </xsl:result-document>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
   <xsl:variable name="ProductID" select="@ID">
       <xsl:value-of select="replace(.,/,-)"/>
    </xsl:variable>
```

use

```
   <xsl:variable name="ProductID" select="replace(@ID, '/', '-')"/>
```

Comment: You beat me by 10 seconds... It might be worth mentioning then that the xsl:result-document href refers to `$ProductId`, not `$ProductID` and the case would need to be adjusted to match.